# No Output Voltage On Power Mux

Tags: voltage, power, current, multiplexer

I am building a board based on a working reference design. I've obtained the assembled board based on my design but the '3V3_OUT' signal is failing to carry power anywhere on the board.

The issue seems to be with the power mux ([TPS2113ADRBR](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2113a.pdf)) as this is where the 3V3_OUT signal is distributed. I am measuring no voltage on the OUT pin (pin7). The two voltage input pins (battery and USB) are both measuring 3.2V (pin6 and pin8 respectively).

I am very much learning this stuff and may be in over my head but I do notice that there is no via under my mux, I am not sure if that may be of concern. Ground planes are used for both layers.

My design which is *not* producing voltage out on pin 7: 
[image]
[image]

The reference design which is *correctly* working: 
[image]
[image]

The schematic used for both designs: 
[image]

Comment: Please run ratsnest on EAGLE so we can see the ground plane. How much current are you trying to draw from 3V3_OUT? It does have thermal protection, so if you're on the high end of the specified power dissipation it won't work without heat dissipation vias on the pad. The datasheet specifies "Must be connected to large copper area in order to meet stated package dissipation ratings."

Comment: @MapleTronix I've updated the images with ratsnest run. I'm measuring .10 mA on 3V3_OUT. What you are describing would make sense as I failed to place vias throughout the board and under this mux which my reference design did do. Is there a way I can test that thermal protection is preventing operation?

Comment: Did it get hot? Any thermal camera?

Comment: You show a complete different PCB. Is this how it has been produced or is it the suggested new one?

Comment: @Huisman I've updated the images with ratsnest showcasing the ground plane. The second image is the already working design. The first one is my design which involves a different layout. In my re-routing it seems that the ground plane EAGLE draws gets isolated in certain areas thus leaving some GND pads unconnected.

So it would appear that your original answer may be correct although for components not shown in the picture. I've patched the GND connections for some of these and I'm now getting a voltage on output, although much lower than anticipated.

Comment: @nullsec Yes you have to be careful, having a top layer ground plane doesn't garantee each GND pad on the top will be connected. Sometimes your clearance requirements (specified in the DRC options) prevent the pad from connecting to the plane. Always run an ERC and DRC and run through every error to make sure you're OK with it before generating your final gerbers. It's the only way to be sure your layout is equivalent to your schematic.

Comment: Do you have a special reason to use 100k for R2 and 20k for R11? Why not short them directly to ground?

Comment: What current are you trying to draw from the output? If it is more than 0.5A (=500/R13) the current limit will kick in. I can't find in the datasheet if the internal high-side power MOSFETs are being pinched or that the IC will go in hickup mode. In both situations, the (average) output voltage will be lower than expected.

Comment: @nullsec You edited the question and removed the most relevant pictures to answer it. Now this question make little sense.

Comment: @Huisman The design I'm referencing outputs 3.2V @ 0.1 mA. I'm outputing .710V @ 0 mA. There doesn't seem to be any current. Before I corrected the GND issue I was outputting 0 Volts as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't connect pin 5.
I would suggest trying to make a connection south or east of pin 5 to the ground plane by carefully scratching the FR4 above that ground plane.
However, C46 neither seems to be connected to GND. If there are more unconnected components, you'd better redesign the PCB. See yellow arrows in picture below.

Make sure you use a DRC. DRC would have detected these unconnected components.

[image]

Comment: Always do a DRC check on designs, and set up the DRC right

Comment: DRC did show my GND pins as unconnected but with the ground plane I made the assumption (maybe a wrong one) that routing those wouldn't be necessary. The eagle project file I was referencing had done the same and I have that working board in hand.

Comment: No. They did not automatically connect.